# Can the Expresso Store download tag deliver web page urls?

Tags: expresso-store

Is it possible to use the download tag (https://exp-resso.com/docs/download_tag.html) in Expresso Store to deliver a url of a web page and not to download a file.

I'm looking for a way to sell access to individual channel entries.

Thanks for any ideas on this...

Regards
Lee

Comment: How do you mean? You don't need the download tag, just hide or show the URL based on whether or not the order is paid.

Answer (score 1):

The download tag would not allow you to just show a URL if the order has been paid. You could however wrap the content within a `{exp:store:orders}` tag pair then use the conditional `{if is_order_paid}` to only show the content if the order has indeed been paid for.

Also I have seen in the past someone create similar functionality by adding a custom field to the content that they wanted to secure that basically had the entry_id of the product that could be purchased. So for example let say your product with an entry_id of 25 was purchased. That product granted access to some content in another channel, in the other channel you would need a field (playa, relationship, text fields or similar) that you entered the value 25 in. Then in your template you would need to write a custom query to search the `exp_store_orders` tables for the currently logged in members orders then check the `exp_store_order_items` for the corresponding ordered items to see if one of the items the currently logged in member purchased was indeed the entry_id that you specified earlier (in this case 25).

Having said that your best bet would be to extract that query into a little custom plugin instead of having that all at the template level.